# 1>Program.cs(59,21,59,25): error CS0103: The name '' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

This is the code i wrote to practise Classes. I'm a complete beginner (I've only learnt for a day) and I can findout what I'm doing wrong, on other posts i only saw problems like this inside the same class. Near the end of the code it tells me that "Dogs" doesn't exist in the context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace cs_tut1 //a felhasználó megadja :állat suly, magasság. a program megnézi hogy azonos életkor(1év kül megengedett) és azonos suly (4kg megengedett) van e olyan állat majd kiirja a nevét és adatait.
{
    class Animal
    {
        public void RandomDataGen()
        {
            int[,] Dogs = new int[1, 2];
            int[] Weight = new int[2];//contains the random weight of dogs
            int[] Height = new int[2];//contains the random height of dogs
            Random weight = new Random();

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                Weight[j] = weight.Next(4, 60);
            }

            Random height = new Random();

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                Height[j] = height.Next(30, 85);
            }

            //insert numbers to 2D array
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                Dogs[0, j] = Weight[j];
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                Dogs[1, j] = Height[j];
            }
        }
    }
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Animal dataAnimal = new Animal();
            dataAnimal.RandomDataGen();

            int UserWeight;
            int UserHeight;

            //Asks for the user's dog's data
            Console.Write("Please enter weight:");
            UserWeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter height:");
            UserHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //Looks for data similar to user's
            for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                if (Dogs[0, i] != 1)
                {

                }
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you declared `Dogs` in `RandomDataGen` and it can't go outside of that method.

Comment: You don't need to declare more than one `Random` instance. Just create one (usually named `random` or `rnd`) and use that for both `weight` and `height`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Dogs[,]` is defined inside the method `RandomDataGen`. This means that it's local to that method. No other classes can access it; in fact no methods in the same class can even access it. In order to access it from another class or method, you would need to have the `RandomDataGen` method return the array to the caller.

Here's how to return the array:

1. Change the return type of the `RandomDataGen` method from `void` to `int[,]`
2. At the end of the `RandomDataGen` method, add the line: `return Dogs;`

Then to consume the array, you can define a new one inside your `Main` method and assign the return value of `RandomDataGen` to it:

```
int[,] Dogs = dataAnimal.RandomDataGen();
```

For example:

```
class Animal
{
    public int[,] RandomDataGen()
    {
        int[,] Dogs = new int[1, 2];

        // And the rest of the code is the same here

        return Dogs;
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        Animal dataAnimal = new Animal();
        int[,] Dogs = dataAnimal.RandomDataGen();

        // And the rest of the code is the same here
    }
}
```

---

Side note on the code in your `RandomDataGen` method: You only need to declare one `Random` instance for a class, and it can be used anywhere. This will help keep the random numbers more random, because the class is seeded by the system time by default, so if you create more than one in a short enough period of time, they will both produce the same random sequences.

One other problem is that you're assigning more items to the first index than you've defined. It appears that the first index of your array holds the weight and the height, yet you've defined it's size as `1`. That should be changed to `2`: `int[,] Dogs = new int[2, 2];`

You also can reduce the number of loops you're doing, since you're looping through the same index 4 times (once to pick a random weight, once to pick a random height, once to set the weight values, and a fourth time to set the height values). Instead, you can just combine the actions of each loop inside a single loop.

For example:

```
class Animal
{
    // In general, you only need one instance of `Random` per class
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public int[,] RandomDataGen()
    {
        int[,] Dogs = new int[2, 2];
        int weightIndex = 0;
        int heightIndex = 1;

        //insert numbers to 2D array
        for (int dog = 0; dog < 2; dog++)
        {
            Dogs[weightIndex, dog] = rnd.Next(4, 60);
            Dogs[heightIndex, dog] = rnd.Next(30, 85);
        }

        return Dogs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put method `RandomDataGen` in class `MainClass`, then take the variable declarations (for variables that are used in `Main()`) out of the method and also put them in class `MainClass`, outside of the method. You don't need the class Animal for this purpose.